# Determine the largest possible value of $⌊K⌋$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

It is known that the real constant $K$ satisfies the inequality
$$(\frac{2}{a+b})^2 +a^3+b^3+\frac {1}{ab}\ge K (ab)^{\frac{1}{4}}$$

for every two positive real numbers $a$ and $b$. Determine the largest possible value of $⌊K⌋$.

My working:

how to proceed? Using $AM\ge GM\ge HM?$ like this?
$$\frac{(\frac{2}{a+b})^2 +a^3+b^3+\frac {1}{ab}}{4}\ge (\frac{2}{ab})^{\frac{1}{4}}$$
$$\frac{K (ab)^{\frac{1}{4}}}{4}\ge (\frac{2}{ab})^{\frac{1}{4}}$$
but I don't think this helps, and I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AM-GM, but more carefully to get the minimum needed.

For e.g. the following is prompted by a guess that $a=b=1$ may be when minimum is achieved, which will prove below.  Note we ensure the AM-GMs below all achieve equality when $a=b=1$.

First, note
$$\left(\frac2{a+b}\right)^2+ 2\frac{a^3+b^3}2\geqslant 3\sqrt[3]{(a^2-ab+b^2)^2}\geqslant 3(ab)^{2/3}$$

Further, again by AM-GM, $$3(ab)^{2/3}+\frac1{ab}\geqslant4(ab)^{1/4}$$

Hence
$$\frac1{(ab)^{1/4}}\left[\left(\frac2{a+b}\right)^2+ a^3+b^3 + \frac1{ab} \right]\geqslant 4$$
with equality possible when $a=b=1$, hence this is the minimum, which has to be then the maximum possible $K$.

Answer (score 1):

If $K\leq0$, our inequality is obviously true.

Let $K>0$ and $a+b$ be a constant.

Thus, $$\frac{4}{(a+b)^2}+a^3+b^3+\frac{1}{ab}-K\sqrt[4]{ab}=\frac{4}{(a+b)^2}+(a+b)^3-3(a+b)ab+\frac{1}{ab}-K\sqrt[4]{ab}$$ decreases as function of $ab$, which says that it's enough to check our inequality for a maximal value of $ab$, which happens for $a=b$.

Thus, $$\max{K}=\min_{a>0}\frac{\frac{1}{a^2}+2a^3+\frac{1}{a^2}}{\sqrt{a}}$$ and by AM-GM we obtain:
$$\frac{\frac{1}{a^2}+2a^3+\frac{1}{a^2}}{\sqrt{a}}=2\left(\sqrt{a^5}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^5}}\right)\geq4.$$
The equality occurs for $a=1$, which gives the answer: $4.$